# How to make a route similar to the open container route

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-routes

I want to push replacement using the navigator but have a route similar to what the `OpenContainer()` from the [animations](https://pub.dev/packages/animations) package. Using a Hero doesn't work as I am animating from a `Container()` to a `Scaffold()` so the width of the widget just cuts to be the width of the screen and only the height animates.

The Adobe XD prototype looks something like this: https://cln.sh/ugu0Sq.

I want the animation to look exactly like the `OpenContainer()` route animation. I can't use an `OpenContainer()` because I want to `pushReplacement()` rather than `push()`. I also don't want the `Hero()` to animate every time, if the user navigates to the page normally through the bottomNavBar, I want no animations to occur, but if they click on the widget on

Answer (score 0):

try this example, change push to pushReplacement, change speed of page transition:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(height: 200, color: Colors.blue),
          Hero(
            tag: 'YearReport',
            child: Container(
              height: 150,
              child: Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text("Year Report                         70%"),
                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                    child: Text("YR"),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    print(curveList.length);
                    Navigator.of(context).push(PageRouteBuilder(
                        pageBuilder: (context, animation, anotherAnimation) {
                          return Scaffold(
                            body: Column(
                              children: [
                                Hero(
                                  tag: 'YearReport',
                                  child: Container(
                                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                    child: Text("Year Report", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60)),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(height: 200, color: Colors.red),
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Container(color: Colors.green),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        transitionDuration: Duration(
                            milliseconds:
                                3000), //Change your page transition speed
                        transitionsBuilder:
                            (context, animation, anotherAnimation, child) {
                          animation = CurvedAnimation(
                              curve: Curves.linear, parent: animation);
                          return Align(
                            child: SizeTransition(
                              sizeFactor: animation,
                              child: child,
                              axisAlignment: 0.0,
                            ),
                          );
                        }));
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: I don't want it to expand like that. I want it to expand like an `OpenContainer()` where the sides expand and the top and bottom expand as well.

Comment: Any answer yet? I need this too